# Javascript how to sort an javascript array in parts?

Tags: javascript

I have an (JS)array from a query on mij page, and it look like this:

```
12349,1,1,1,12345,2,2,2,123457,3,3,3
```

The numbers with 5 digits are example "timestamps", the one digit are prices that belong to the timestamp. I want to sort the array based on the timestamps, but also want that the prices stay behind the timestamp. So after soring the array has to look like this:

```
12345,2,2,2,12349,1,1,1,123457,3,3,3
```

How to do this?

Comment: You might want to reconsider your data structure choices.

Answer (score 5):

```
var input=[12349,1,1,1,12345,2,2,2,123457,3,3,3]
```

Step one: Convert to a slightly better structure (I don't know the semantics, but you do). This step should not normally be neccessary:

```
var temp=[];
for(int i=0; i<input.length; i+=4){ //assuming the form T,x,x,x{,T,x,x,x}
  temp.push(input.slice(i,i+3))
}
```

Step two: Do the sorting. This is the only thing you'd need to do if you were using proper data structures (except then you'd use `return a.timestamp-b.timestamp`):

```
temp.sort(function(a,b){return a[0]-b[0]})
```

Step three **(optional)**: convert back:

```
var out=[];
for(int i=0; i<temp.length; i++){
  for(int j=0; j<temp[i].length; j++){
    out.push(temp[i][j])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to handle it:

```
var source = [12345,2,2,2,12349,1,1,1,123457,3,3,3];

function sort() {
    var timeslices = [];
    var curr;
    for (var i=0; i < source.length; i++) {
        if (source[i] > 9999) {
            if (curr) {
                timeslices.push(curr);
            }
            curr = {
                time : source[i],
                prices: []
            };
        }
        else {
            curr.prices.push(source[i]);
        }
    }
    timeslices.push(curr);
    return timeslices.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.time - b.time;
    });
}

console.dir(sort());
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4x4qd/)

I'm making no assumptions about how many prices are associated with each timestamp. I'm also assuming that your 6 digit number is also supposed to be a timestamp.

I didn't flatten your array back out again, but you can do that if you want, but it makes more sense to keep your data in a more useful structure.

Comment: `source[i] > 9999` smells bad ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak: Quickest way to tell if the number is 5 or more digits as per the requirements.

Comment: Not sure this is actually the specification; it just serves as a pointer to the example IMO

Comment: @JanDvorak: From the question `The numbers with 5 digits are example "timestamps"` (admittedly, I added the word `digits` myself). Sounds like a specification to me. In lieu of a better definition, it's what I went with. You choose to instead go with the unstated specification that every timestamp is followed by 3 prices, which smells worse to me ;)

Comment: I guess the word "example" in "example timestamps" plays a role here; as if by implying the real timestamps need not be five-digit.

Comment: I'm upvoting, just in case your interpretation is correct

Comment: @JanDvorak: Thanks. Now I'm wondering who down-voted me!

Answer (score -1):

Storing data in an array like that is really wrong, you should use a multidimensional array probably:

```
[0]=>{[0]12345,[1]1}
[1]=>{[0]23456,[1]2}
```

or even better an associative array:

```
[0]=>{['timestamp']12345,['price']1}
[1]=>{['timestamp']23456,['price']2}
```

i hope it helps you.

EDIT: this isnt code, i just tried to show the structure of the array.

Comment: In which language is this valid syntax? Not in javascript.

Comment: Yeah sorry i didnt make it clear, i just tried to show the "internal" representation of the data, it isnt code.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: Your right, i though it was better to re implement the array creation than give a solution over the wrong structure.